# Errors in lib.d.ts with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have an application that was originally built on TypeScript 0.9.1.  I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, updated my Windows PATH variable to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8 and added TypeScriptToolsVersion 1.8 to the .csproj.

The correct version of typescript is stored locally for intellisense at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript

I receive the following errors in lib.d.ts:[image]

When running tsc -v, I get 1.8.34.  When using the Help -> About, I get version 1.8.35.

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated as I've been unable to find this problem reported anywhere else and, as far as I can see, everything is installed correctly and pointed at the correct compiler.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to have 'fixed itself' by deleting the .suo file in the solution directory, at least in terms of the build errors. Sometimes the intellisense errors still pop up.

This seems like it's still an essential problem with either TypeScript or Visual Studio, but at least I seem to now be past it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a conflict between two installs of TypeScript.

Comment: I don't see how that could be.  I've uninstalled / reinstalled TS multiple times now.  When running tsc -v from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8 and  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript as well as globally, I consistently get 1.8.34